# How to start weblogic service using sudo with another user?

Tags: sudo, weblogic

On Centos 6.8 server, I need to start weblogic-service from test user, and I need the process owner to be weblogic, not the test user.

I also have to start weblogic with nohup, and put it in backbground like this :

`#nohup ./startweblogic &`

Things I have done are as follow:

I have added test user to sudoers so it can run the start script

I run the following command, but still the process owner is not weblogic.

`#su -p -s /bin/sh weblogic  "nohup /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/startWebLogic.sh &"`

Comment: So you edited sudoer file, but then did not use sudo. What were you expecting?

Comment: i have edited the sudoer file, read the question again, i wrote "I have added test user to sudoers so it can run the start script"

Comment: I said that you edited the sudoer file (“So you edited sudoer file”), in my comment. You read my comment again. In you question after editing it, you go on to **not run sudo**. Therefore the edits will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've setup the sudoers file as such :

```
test ALL=(weblogic) NOPASSWD: /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/startWebLogic.sh
```

That will allow the `test` user to run the command as user `weblogic`, without needing a password (if you don't want that, remove `NOPASSWD:`.

Also as you intend to run Weblogic in background it's nice to set it to use auto-login feature with boot.properties, so it's not asking for user/password.
Put a file called `boot.properties` in `/u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/your_server_name/security` (create security directory if needed) with the folllowing content :

```
username=your_weblogic_username
password=your_weblogic_password
```

Then login as `test` and run `sudo -u weblogic nohup /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/startWebLogic.sh &`

And you get :

```
root      3133  0.0  0.1  37084  6208 pts/1    S    17:47   0:00 sudo -u weblogic nohup /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/startWebLogic.sh
weblogic  3134  0.0  0.0   7112  2912 pts/1    S    17:47   0:00  \_ /bin/sh /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/startWebLogic.sh
weblogic  3135  0.0  0.0   7252  3508 pts/1    S    17:47   0:00      \_ /bin/sh /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/bin/startWebLogic.sh
weblogic  3168  2.8 10.8 2606220 437004 pts/1  Sl   17:47   0:15          \_ /home/weblogic/jdk/bin/java -server -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=/u01/Oracle/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true -Djava.system.class.loader=com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader -javaagent:/u01/Oracle/wlserver/server/lib/debugpatch-agent.jar -da -Dwls.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver/server -Dweblogic.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver/server weblogic.Server
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
su -p -s /bin/sh weblogic -c "nohup /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/startWebLogic.sh &"
```

Note "-c" before command in quotes.

Also make sure 'weblogic' user has permission to write into current directory because 'nohup' will redirect server's output into 'nohup.out' file in current directory.

Comment: it asks for password